# How to tell a Django view who called it?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have two Django views that render two separate templates.  Each of these templates will contain a link to the same third view.

That third view will render a template that should display one button if the first Django view/template link redirected to it but render a different button if the second view/template link redirected to it. 
The `URI` for the link in each of these templates will be something like this:

```
/members/near/<from_uid>/profile/<to_uid>/
```

What is the most robust or "best-practice" way to tell the third view who called it?  Should I create links like the following?

```
/members/near/<from_uid>/profile/<to_uid>/from/<view_name>
/members/near/<from_uid>/profile/<to_uid>/from/<view_name>
```

Would it be better to examine the `HTTP` referer header field in the request?  Or is there some other better technique for doing this?

By the way, I realize my `URI` isn't `RESTful` but I don't feel that I understand `REST` sufficiently well to create `RESTful URIs`, particularly when I have to pass multiple arguments as I do here with the `from_uid` and `to_uid` arguments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a part of the URL to be used as a parameters. Each parameter will be set based on the regex provided.  an example here. One view can handle all your urls that contain the three parameters you mentioned.

```
url(r'^members/near/(?P<from_uid>\d+)/profile/(?P<to_uid>\d+)/from//(?P<view_name>\W+)/$', MyView.as_view(), name = 'my_named_view')
```

Then in your view you just pull these parameters from the url

```
from_uid = self.kwargs['from_uid']
to_uid = self.kwargs['to_uid']
view_name = self.kwargs['view_name']

if view_name == "....":
    # render to template1
elif view_name == "....":
    # render to template2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GET parameters like this...

Template 1:
`<a href="/third/view/?from=view1">Link</a>`

Template 2:
`<a href="/third/view/?from=view2">Link</a>`

And in your third view...
`from_view = self.request.GET.pop('from')
if from_view == 'view1':
  ...
elif from_view == 'view2':
  ...`

GET parameters are more appropriate than URL-captured parameters in a situation like this.

Comment: Thanks ejb.  I like your solution but the other is more consistent with my codebase.  I'll try your approach on future projects.